# Showing application/octet-stream data in img tag in angular application

Tags: html, angular, image, api

From API, i am getting the data as application/octet-stream response. The data is an image file. I want to show the image in my angular component html.

I tried getting the data as blob using HttpClient and converting it into data url using FileReader, then the data was converted into data url but the img tag was not showing the image.

How can i show the image in img tag.

Comment: Have you tried this approach `<img [src]="data.imageurl">`? Check this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-src) in Angular.

Comment: i dont have the image url.. i have the image data as blob

Comment: Content security policy was blocking the data urls, i added the "data:" in img-url policy and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code with angular :

// create element img im html file

// in ts file  create URL to display with blob response

// remember blob is reponse from api or anyware

**const  imageUrl =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);**

// get element from html file

**const  element = document.getElementById("image");**

// set url in element

**element?.setAttribute("src",imageUrl);**

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.